# Markercluster Doubling Markers

Tags: wordpress, leaflet, mapbox, markerclusterer

For some reason, Markercluster is doubling the markers in a group. For example, when I click on a group I see four individual markers instead of two. The names are duplicated too. I looked through other posts but am still confused by this. Thanks!

```
<script>
  var mapData = <?php echo wp_json_encode($mapData); ?>;
  var map = L.map('map').setView([40, 0], 2);
  var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();

  L.mapbox.accessToken = 'myToken';

  var geocoder = L.mapbox.geocoder('mapbox.places');

  for ( var i = 0; i < mapData.length; i++ )
  {
     geocoder.query(mapData[i].city, showLoc);
  }

  L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=myToken', {
maxZoom: 18,
attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
    '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
    'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
id: 'mapbox.streets'
   }).addTo(map);

function showLoc (err, data) {
   var city = data.results.query.join(' ');
   for ( var i = 0; i < mapData.length; i++ )
{

    if ( mapData[i].city.toLowerCase() === city ) {
        var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(data.latlng[0], data.latlng[1]), {
                        icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-color': 'c70c2b'}),
                        title: mapData[i].name
                    });
        //new L.Marker([data.latlng[0], data.latlng[1]], 2)
    marker.bindPopup("<strong>" + mapData[i].name + "</strong>")

    markers.addLayer(marker);
}
}
markers.addTo(map);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I figured it out. Very simple fix. Had to move `var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();` in my `showLoc (err, data)` function. I think it has to do with declaring it after the map tiles load. Not sure though.